# Two Photo icons on Moto G following Lollipop upgrade

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, app-icons

After upgrading my Moto G 1st gen smartphone to Lollipop I now have 2 photo icons.  Is there any other way to delete the duplicate other than a factory reset?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Having a basic understanding of android I believe it is one of the many apps found in the app drawer.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling either app?

Comment: OK, that's definitely the drawer. Please try the following: Go to your Android settings, chose *Apps › All*, scroll to "Photos". Is the entry duplicate here as well? If so, try opening one, and see whether you can disable it. Does the second one stay, or gets disabled along? Also worth a try: Check whether the app drawer offers to sort its entries – e.g. sort it by install-time, and then back to alphabetically. If it's really a dupe entry, that might remove it.

Comment: I was able to disable one in the app drawer while still keeping the other and it works.  To note app that is working uses 1.69MG in storage space and is version 1 while the disabled used up 32KB and is version 1.1.40301.  When I tried disabling the other app first both disappeared from the app drawer.  Even though it is only 32KB in storage space is it part of the overall storage usage?  Thanks for your help Izzy. Thanks to Andrew for your suggestion as well.

Comment: I believe that Photos app is or was an activity from the Google+ app (I didn't complete follow the conversation I saw about it) so I believe beemer5's answer is likely to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable and remove Google+, then reinstall it from the app store, I did this to mine this morning and now its fine.